# Indices from Meshgrid matlab

Tags: matlab, marching-cubes

I am stuck here since so long. Please help me.

For the following code:

Original **"I"** dimensions are 217x181x181

[nX,nY,nZ] = size(I);

[X,Y,Z] = meshgrid(1:nX,1:nY,1:nZ);

after Meshgrid X, Y, Z are of dimensions 181x217x181

Now from **"I"** how to find values in C matrix such that the dimensions of X, Y, Z matches with that of C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your case, you will want to use [`ndgrid`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html) instead of [`meshgrid`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html), as this will give you matrices that are 217x181x181. You should take a look at the following for a good comparison of the two functions:

[What is the difference between the NDGRID and MESHGRID functions in MATLAB?](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/99720-what-is-the-difference-between-the-ndgrid-and-meshgrid-functions-in-matlab)

To summarize:

> NDGRID is to be used for higher dimensionality use and for when you want the results to reflect matrix/array notation:
>
> MESHGRID is to be used for visualizing data and should be used primarily for when plotting two or three dimensional data.